# Create a new block and add it to a template

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am a Magento beginner and need help with creating a new custom block.
Basically I just want the block to show "hello" if it is called.

1. Module installation xml file, **app/etc/modules/MyExtensions_HelloBlock.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
           </MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. Module configuration xml file, **app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/etc/config.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
               <version>0.0.1</version>
           </MyExtensions_HelloBlock>
       </modules>
       <global>
           <blocks>
               <helloblock>
                   <class>MyExtensions_HelloBlock_Block</class>
               </helloblock>
           </blocks> 
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
3. Block class, **app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Hello.php**

   ```
   <?php
   class MyExtensions_HelloBlock_Block_Hello extends Mage_Core_Block_Template 
   {    
       public function hello()
       {
           echo "hello";
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Template file for the block, **app/design/frontend/default/default/template/helloblock/hello.phtml**

   ```
   <?php
       $this->hello();
   ?>
   ```

Then I call my new block like this in the template "app/design/frontend/venedor/default/template/page/1column.phtml":

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('helloblock/hello')->setTemplate('helloblock/hello.phtml')->toHtml();
```

**Result:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in
>   /app/design/frontend/venedor/default/template/page/1column.phtml
>   on line 58

I was following this [tutorial](http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-create-a-new-block-and-add-it-to-a-template/).

Comment: Dude, Block file should be inside "Block" directory, app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Block/Hello.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Block** folder is missing

Your block's path should be **app/code/local/MyExtensions/HelloBlock/Block/Hello.php**